# Bucket sort descending order?

Tags: c++, sorting

I am trying to a program using c++ to sort the array in ascending and descending order. I only created the ascending order using bucket sort:

```
void bucketSort (int data[], int n)
{
int x = 65537; //range is [1,65536]
int buckets[x];  //Create empty buckets
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)  //Initialize all buckets to 0
buckets[i] = 0;

//Increment the # of times each element is present in the input
//array. Insert them in the buckets
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
buckets[data[i]]++;

//Sort using insertion sort and link
for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < x; j++)
for (int k = buckets[j]; k > 0; k--)
  data[i++] = j;
}
```

But I don't know how to do it in descending order. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing here is a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) and not a [bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort).

Now, to sort the elements in descending order, Change the 3rd `for` loop as follows:

```
for(int i = 0, j = x; j >= 0; j--))
```

Comment: thanks for reminding me, I got confused with the bucket and counting sort.

Answer (score 0):

`std::reverse(data, data + n)` at the end,

or iterate bucket in descending order. (`j = x - 1 to 0`)